# Why is my Mac XAMPP server not working?

Tags: macos, xampp

I have a working website on local host. I port forward the IP of my mac where the starting port is 80 and the ending port is also 80. I then used a tool called Open Port Check (http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and it said that port 80 was open. It works when I connect to the local IP of my mac 192.168.0.12 but not when I try to connect to my public IP and it just says in the top tab Connecting... for a minute or so and then says problem loading page. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your router to forward port 80 requests to your Mac's local IP.